# Authenticating MySQL spring datasource connection using SHA256

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I have a spring datasource connection which connects to MySQL database

```
<bean id="sceLocationsDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://IP:PORT/SCHEMA" />
        <property name="username" value="user" />
        <property name="password" value="my_password_goes_here" />

    </bean>
```

when I try to connect I get the below exception

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Public Key Retrieval is not allowed
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:383)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1023)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:997)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:983)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:928)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.authentication.Sha256PasswordPlugin.nextAuthenticationStep(Sha256PasswordPlugin.java:108)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1791)
```

it seems also, this problem is know at [here](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=75670)

my question is how to add SHA256 authentication to the spring datasource configuration?